# Reorder factor levels using names

Tags: r, r-factor

I can reorder the levels of a factor using their indices like this

```
factor(iris$Species,levels(iris$Species)[c(3:1)])
```

However if I try to reorder the same factor by name, it does not work:

```
factor(iris$Species,levels(iris$Species)[c("virginica", "versicolor", "setosa")])
```

Is there a way to reorder the levels of a factor using their names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you use the basic variant with giving new level names:

```
factor(iris$Species, levels=c("virginica", "versicolor", "setosa"))
```

Be sure to list *all* level names, though. Otherwise, you will end up with `NA` values.

However, for completeness: If you rely on the order of the elements within a factor, you probably should used `ordered` instead of `factor`. That is just a factor with, well, *ordered* levels, or, more mathematically, a relation `<` between the factor levels. See:

```
> ordered(1:3, levels=c('1', '3', '2'))
[1] 1 2 3
Levels: 1 < 3 < 2
```