# R - obtaining the levels in a factor

Tags: r, r-factor

I am trying to write a loop which needs to be able to identify the levels in a factor.  I am struggling with obtaining the levels

For example:

```
x<-c("male","female","male","male")
x<-as.factor(x)
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like
e.g.

```
>x.level[1]
male 
>x.level[2]
female
```

How can I create x.level?

Comment: try `x.level <- levels(x)`

Comment: Reading the help files is usually helpful. In the 'see also' section of `?factor` it says "*‘levels’ and ‘nlevels’ for accessing the levels*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this...?

```
 x <- relevel(x, ref="male")  # use `relevel` just to reorder levels
> x.level <- levels(x)
> x.level[1]
[1] "male"
> x.level[2]  
[1] "female"
```

Comment: yes thank you!! Just one more query - if there are more than two levels (e.g. blue, red, yellow) and I want to reorder it according to my preference (e.g. red, blue, yellow), how can i do this/

Comment: @Si Generally, new questions should be posted as such (if they don't already exist (e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231370/how-do-i-reorder-a-factor) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468420/reorder-factor-levels-using-names)) on SO). You can use the `levels` arg to `factor` to specify the level order. e.g.: `factor(c('red', 'yellow', 'blue'), c('yellow', 'blue', 'red'))`.

Answer (score 0):

for ffdf it is slightly different. though not asked here in its context I thought it might help someone handling big data (which can fit into ffdf). length() of it will give you total number of levels. Since ffdf does not handle char as char as of today, this is best way to keep track of number of chr turned into factor levels which might be holding up the memory.

virtual(myffdf$factorcolumn)$Levels